# How to auto update users IE browser bookmarks when changing a site's url?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, browser

I have a user base that is forced to use IE 7. I have created a web site that will be getting a new URL. Is there a way to force a bookmark to update to point to the new URL when a user hits the old site via a bookmark in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Your best bet is to include a message on the old site that says, "We've moved, and here's the new site. Remember to update your bookmarks." You can also add a Javascript button that will make it simple for unsophisticated users (http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html).

Answer (score 2):

No - there's no way to forcibly update people's bookmarks, and that is a Good Thing™.

However it looks like it's possible to provide people the option to do so, by giving them a Javascript popup as described [here](http://www.hypergurl.com/bookmark.html).  This might be what you're after, though it might not supersede or replace an existing bookmark.

It also fails gracefully for noncompatible browsers, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working within an organization, you may also want to have your desktop support team push out, as part of the software updates, links to your new site.  This is especially useful if the site is the default home page of most of the users.